# Create a new array based on existing array? (nested loops)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider this array of objects below:

```
const selectedArr = 
[
  [
      {
          "id": "dc52b988-47ee-4948-84e0-b17e2ac76502",
          "groupName": "Dairy",
          "groupDetail": "A dairy is a business enterprise established for the harvesting or processing of animal milk – mostly from cows or buffaloes, but also from goats, sheep, horses, or camels – for human consumption",
          "groupImage": {
              "imageAddress": "9a2949ce-978a-4807-a40d-4256f41e23b3.png",
              "imageTitle": "dairy-product"
          },
          "childGroups": [
              {
                  "id": "2f4f1812-a5ee-4342-bd26-1c3edf4d17e5",
                  "groupName": "diary child 1",
                  "groupDetail": "",
                  "groupImage": null,
                  "childGroups": []
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "id": "43f8de6c-ac69-4fc9-b681-ed69f76f7983",
          "groupName": "Beverage",
          "groupDetail": "A drink is a liquid intended for human consumption. In addition to their basic function of satisfying thirst, drinks play important roles in human culture.",
          "groupImage": {
              "imageAddress": "c9a1ef69-6226-4f31-8766-b602ddee096d.png",
              "imageTitle": "beverage"
          },
          "childGroups": [
              {
                  "id": "938a4a93-d613-457f-8388-27f93cf46039",
                  "groupName": "Liquor",
                  "groupDetail": "This is Liquor product group",
                  "groupImage": {
                      "imageAddress": "0a32df32-ea22-4d9c-a1fd-16312ef2c14c.jpg",
                      "imageTitle": "istockphoto-459018635-612x612"
                  },
                  "childGroups": []
              },
              {
                  "id": "e64a6e41-290e-437d-8b81-591422464ce9",
                  "groupName": "Juices",
                  "groupDetail": "This is Juices product group",
                  "groupImage": {
                      "imageAddress": "18b75b08-5f74-4ad5-8fc0-cda0980e847c.jpg",
                      "imageTitle": "healthy-juice-cleanse-recipes-1"
                  },
                  "childGroups": []
              },
              {
                  "id": "d1634118-b590-43e5-8c05-9d1a90cddf7b",
                  "groupName": "Soda",
                  "groupDetail": "This is soda product group",
                  "groupImage": {
                      "imageAddress": "fe08b916-333d-4e5d-abfc-5cb29d335e0e.jpeg",
                      "imageTitle": "adobestock_279692163_editorial_use_only-860x533"
                  },
                  "childGroups": [
                      {
                          "id": "559dd366-8d60-4e14-8d3b-2a8dd53e8ef8",
                          "groupName": "Zero Sugar",
                          "groupDetail": "This is zero sugar sodas",
                          "groupImage": null,
                          "childGroups": []
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  ],
  [
      {
          "id": "d1634118-b590-43e5-8c05-9d1a90cddf7b",
          "groupName": "Soda",
          "groupDetail": "This is soda product group",
          "groupImage": {
              "imageAddress": "fe08b916-333d-4e5d-abfc-5cb29d335e0e.jpeg",
              "imageTitle": "adobestock_279692163_editorial_use_only-860x533"
          },
          "childGroups": [
              {
                  "id": "559dd366-8d60-4e14-8d3b-2a8dd53e8ef8",
                  "groupName": "Zero Sugar",
                  "groupDetail": "This is zero sugar sodas",
                  "groupImage": null,
                  "childGroups": []
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "id": "2f4f1812-a5ee-4342-bd26-1c3edf4d17e5",
          "groupName": "diary child 1",
          "groupDetail": "",
          "groupImage": null,
          "childGroups": []
      }
  ],
  [
      {
          "id": "559dd366-8d60-4e14-8d3b-2a8dd53e8ef8",
          "groupName": "Zero Sugar",
          "groupDetail": "This is zero sugar sodas",
          "groupImage": null,
          "childGroups": []
      }
  ]
]
```

this is a nested (2D) array of some product groups with child product groups that the user has selected and each index is the parent of the next one. (some parent product groups has child and some does not)

**What I need to achieve is if the user selects a productgroup that has children but she doesn't select it's children I only need to put parent in the newSelectedArr but if she select one or more than one child I need to put every child that user selected with no parent. also if parent has no child and user select that parent I need that too.**

```
const newSelectedArr = 
[
  [
    {
      "id": "2f4f1812-a5ee-4342-bd26-1c3edf4d17e5",
      "groupName": "diary child 1",
      "groupDetail": "",
      "groupImage": null,
      "childGroups": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "559dd366-8d60-4e14-8d3b-2a8dd53e8ef8",
      "groupName": "Zero Sugar",
      "groupDetail": "This is zero sugar sodas",
      "groupImage": null,
      "childGroups": []
    }
  ]
]
```

as you can see "diary child 1" is in the second index and "Zero Sugar" is the last one and both has no childGroups (empty array)

what I tried so far is two nested loop that loop:

```js
let newselectedArr= [];
        for (let i = 0; i < selectedArr.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < selectedArr[i].length; j++) {
                if (selectedArr[i][j].childGroups.length) {
                    const find = selectedArr[i][j].childGroups.find(
                        (el) => el.id === selectedArr[i + 1].find((el) => el.id),
                    );
                    console.log(find);
                }
                if (selectedArr[i][j].childGroups.length === 0) {
                    newselectedArr.push(selectedArr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

but it won't work propery.. how can I achieve this?

Comment: "*I need to achieve is a new array based on the last child selected by the user*" - then I think you need to include enough "*[mcve]*" code (HTML, JavaScript, CSS) to allow us to reproduce the user-selection behaviour, so we can work within the constraints you're operating under.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't specific enough; I've clarified my original comment to be clear that we need to see the (relevant) code to reproduce your problem. Going through an Array and creating another Array based on its properties is easy, doing that within the constraints of your user-selection process is the problem. And we can't guess at what code you're using to do that, or what information is available at that point.

Comment: It is not clear to me what *selected* means: how is a selection identified? What is the expected output?

Comment: @DavidThomas oh I see, I try to explain because if I put code here it's too much and complicated. suppose I have some drop-down input that the user can select from it let's call it selectors, selectedArr that I put in the question is created based on each selector (first index is the first selector, the second index is the second selector, and so on.. makes a 2D array), but the problem is I can't send this selectedArr to the server because what it wants from me is the last child of every object (if selected) for that I need to create a newSelectedArr and filter the base selectedArr.

Comment: @DavidThomas for example: from the first input I choose 'Dairy' and the whole object of Dairy should push to the newSelectedArr. thenthe second input should contain Dairy's childGroups as the available for select and you can see in the selectedArr it has one childGroup which is 'diary child 1', if I select this too from the second input then I need to  delete 'Dairy' object form the newSelectedArr and replace it with 'dairy child 1' object

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you correctly, but as far as I understand, you want to extract the children with empty childGroups. To do that you need recursive function call.

```js
const selectedArr = [
      [
          {
              "id": "dc52b988-47ee-4948-84e0-b17e2ac76502",
              "groupName": "Dairy",
              "groupDetail": "A dairy is a business enterprise established for the harvesting or processing of animal milk – mostly from cows or buffaloes, but also from goats, sheep, horses, or camels – for human consumption",
              "groupImage": {
                  "imageAddress": "9a2949ce-978a-4807-a40d-4256f41e23b3.png",
                  "imageTitle": "dairy-product"
              },
              "childGroups": [
                  {
                      "id": "2f4f1812-a5ee-4342-bd26-1c3edf4d17e5",
                      "groupName": "diary child 1",
                      "groupDetail": "",
                      "groupImage": null,
                      "childGroups": []
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "id": "43f8de6c-ac69-4fc9-b681-ed69f76f7983",
              "groupName": "Beverage",
              "groupDetail": "A drink is a liquid intended for human consumption. In addition to their basic function of satisfying thirst, drinks play important roles in human culture.",
              "groupImage": {
                  "imageAddress": "c9a1ef69-6226-4f31-8766-b602ddee096d.png",
                  "imageTitle": "beverage"
              },
              "childGroups": [
                  {
                      "id": "938a4a93-d613-457f-8388-27f93cf46039",
                      "groupName": "Liquor",
                      "groupDetail": "This is Liquor product group",
                      "groupImage": {
                          "imageAddress": "0a32df32-ea22-4d9c-a1fd-16312ef2c14c.jpg",
                          "imageTitle": "istockphoto-459018635-612x612"
                      },
                      "childGroups": []
                  },
                  {
                      "id": "e64a6e41-290e-437d-8b81-591422464ce9",
                      "groupName": "Juices",
                      "groupDetail": "This is Juices product group",
                      "groupImage": {
                          "imageAddress": "18b75b08-5f74-4ad5-8fc0-cda0980e847c.jpg",
                          "imageTitle": "healthy-juice-cleanse-recipes-1"
                      },
                      "childGroups": []
                  },
                  {
                      "id": "d1634118-b590-43e5-8c05-9d1a90cddf7b",
                      "groupName": "Soda",
                      "groupDetail": "This is soda product group",
                      "groupImage": {
                          "imageAddress": "fe08b916-333d-4e5d-abfc-5cb29d335e0e.jpeg",
                          "imageTitle": "adobestock_279692163_editorial_use_only-860x533"
                      },
                      "childGroups": [
                          {
                              "id": "559dd366-8d60-4e14-8d3b-2a8dd53e8ef8",
                              "groupName": "Zero Sugar",
                              "groupDetail": "This is zero sugar sodas",
                              "groupImage": null,
                              "childGroups": []
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ],
      [
          {
              "id": "d1634118-b590-43e5-8c05-9d1a90cddf7b",
              "groupName": "Soda",
              "groupDetail": "This is soda product group",
              "groupImage": {
                  "imageAddress": "fe08b916-333d-4e5d-abfc-5cb29d335e0e.jpeg",
                  "imageTitle": "adobestock_279692163_editorial_use_only-860x533"
              },
              "childGroups": [
                  {
                      "id": "559dd366-8d60-4e14-8d3b-2a8dd53e8ef8",
                      "groupName": "Zero Sugar",
                      "groupDetail": "This is zero sugar sodas",
                      "groupImage": null,
                      "childGroups": []
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "id": "2f4f1812-a5ee-4342-bd26-1c3edf4d17e5",
              "groupName": "diary child 1",
              "groupDetail": "",
              "groupImage": null,
              "childGroups": []
          }
      ],
      [
          {
              "id": "559dd366-8d60-4e14-8d3b-2a8dd53e8ef8",
              "groupName": "Zero Sugar",
              "groupDetail": "This is zero sugar sodas",
              "groupImage": null,
              "childGroups": []
          }
      ]
    ]

    const newArray = [];

    // This function isn't a part of recursive call.
    // But it's required because selectedArr is a nested array,
    // and in order to get the data for recursion, we need a loop.
    const createNewArray = () => {
      selectedArr.forEach(group => {
        extractChild(group);
      })
    }

    // This is the function do all the job recursivly.
    const extractChild = (data) => {
      data.forEach((obj) => {
        obj.childGroups.length == 0 ? newArray.push(obj) : extractChild(obj.childGroups);
      })
    }

    createNewArray();

    console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not only empty childGroups, I need the last child if available and parent, i mean if user select parent and doesn't select any child I need that parent but if select parent and select one or more than one of its child I don't need parent and I need selected children.. sorry if I explain it bad in the question.